# Use Zend ProgressBar with Microsoft iis 7 web server

Tags: php, zend-framework, iis, progress-bar

I work with Zend 1.11.

I am using this script to update a progress bar during long tasks in my controller actions : http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/demos/Zend/ProgressBar/JsPush.php

This script is running perfectly with Apache (tested with EasyPHP on Windows), but doesn't work with IIS 7. All the update calls are done after the end task.

After spending few hours around the web and trying to understand why, I give up...

Is there someones to understand why an d how to fix that?

Could it be a PHP configuration problem?